# Deserialize value of mixed type with JMS Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, jms-serializer

I have some trouble with JMS Serializer - I need to deserialize a dirty JSON with a mixed type for the `score` value. For example:

```
{ label: "hello", score: 50 }
```

Or

```
{ label: "hello", score: true }
```

If I put `@Type("int")`, when the value is a `boolean`, it gets deserialized as `1` or `0`...
I would like to get `100` when the value is `true`, and `0` when the value is `false`.
How could I manage this mixed type on deserialization?

My class:

```
class Lorem 
{
    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @SerializedName("label")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $label;

    /**
     * @Type("int")
     * @SerializedName("score")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $score;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your [custom handler](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers) defining a new `my_custom_type` (or something better named :), which you can then use in your annotations.

Something like this should work:

```
class MyCustomTypeHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribingMethods()
    {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_DESERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'my_custom_type',
                'method' => 'deserializeFromJSON',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * The de-serialization function, which will return always an integer.
     *
     * @param JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor
     * @param int|bool $data
     * @param array $type
     * @return int
     */
    public function deserializeFromJSON(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, $data, array $type)
    {
        if ($data === true) {
            return 100;
        }
        if ($data === false) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the `Type annotation` will cast the value, Maybe you can define an array of Type see [doc](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type) something like that `Type("array<string>,array< boolean>")`

Comment: The `Type` annotation doesn't allow that syntax.